# Getting codeception & phpunit working on MAMP with OS X Lion

Tags: php, macos, unit-testing, mamp

### Running:

- MAMP 2.0.5
- PHP 5.3.6 (bundled with MAMP)
- Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2

My goal is to get the [Codeception](http://codeception.com/) testing framework to work and use within my MAMP project. I'm following [the instructions here](http://codeception.com/install) on how to install it.

Pear is installed and working fine. I am able to get Codeception installed with these commands:

```
$ pear channel-discover codeception.com/pear
$ pear install codeception/Codeception
```

Once installed when I try to run the codecept commands I get the following error:

```
Warning: require_once(Codeception/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/bin/codecept on line 12
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Codeception/autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in /usr/bin/codecept on line 12
```

I think that the issue is caused by either:

- A conflict between MAMP's PHP installation in the one bundled with OS X
- An issue with the include_path in my php.ini or somewhere else

### Also of interest

- When I run the `$ phpunit` command from inside my project folder I get `-bash: phpunit: command not found` but if I run it as `$ /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/phpu
  nit` it works just fine.
- I would expect there to be a `codecept` file in `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/` but there isn't - there is however a `Codeception` folder in `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php`
- I've tried a few different ways to install it, and I guess one of the ways installed Codeception in Lion's copy of php (as opposed to MAMP's) - so I do have a `codecept` file in `/usr/bin/` as well as the `Codeception` folder in `/usr/lib/php/pear/`

### For reference:

- PHP lives here: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php`
- Pear lives here: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/pear`
- PHPUnit lives here: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/phpunit`

Any Help? Suggestions?

---

Thanks to Davert's help - I was able to confirm that this is a conflict with MAMP's copy of PHP and Lion's built-in copy of PHP. To solve the issue I created a new `php.ini` file in `/etc` that was a duplicate of `php.ini.default` and changed the `include_path` to `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is: your PEAR command was executed from bundled PHP. So your primary MAMP PHP libraries in `(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/pear)` were not updated. I suggest you should find the second PEAR were the Codeception was exctually stored. And add path to it into 'include_path' in php.ini.

Yes, PEAR is quite buggy. In next releases a Composer installator will be added.

Also, you can try to use Phar executable.

In this case a Codeception should be executed with:

```
php codecept.phar
```

Comment: Hey Davert, 

Thanks for your your responsiveness and quick reply, much obliged! 

I tried the phar executable but couldn't figure where I should place it or how to get it to work despite the instructions on your site. Can you please clarify how that would work? 

Also when you say "And add path to it into 'include_path' in php.ini." can you explain exactly what that would involve? what should that line of the php.ini read? Thanks again!

Comment: I think you should fix your MAMP PEAR. So, first of all, find where Codeception code was stored. Find for example a 'Codecept.php' and a directory Codeception which contains this file. Codeception dir should be found in your bundled PEAR path. Remember this path and in your MAMP version edit php.ini: `include_path = ".:new_path_to_pear"`. If you still have problems, contact me in Skype.

Comment: Got it to work. As I suspected this was a conflict between Lion's built-in PHP and MAMP's copy of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that worked for me was to edit /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/codecept and replace /usr/bin/php at the first line by /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php