# Zend framework zf command and Netbeans registration don't work

Tags: zend-framework, netbeans, frameworks

I am working on MacOSX Lion, and I am trying to install Zend Framework. I did this in the past and it was easy, now it doesn't work. After registration of ZF with Netbeans, which gives an error, the zf show version command generates this error:

> Warning: include_once(NetBeansCommandsProvider.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ZF11/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'NetBeansCommandsProvider.php' for inclusion (include_path='/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ZF11/library:/Users/payam/php_library/ZendFramework-1.11.8/library:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.0.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/php/zend:.:/usr/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ZF11/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146

Some people say I have to fix `.zf.ini` file, but such a file is not created on MacOSX. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Finder won't show you files beginning with a `.` by default. Try using Terminal

Comment: I tried that. It didn't return anything related. I think .zf.ini is a file that is created on Linux. I removed MAMP and Netbeans and installed MAMP fresh with a fresh ZF without installing Netbeans, in the terminal I entered sh zf.sh and I got the same error.

Comment: I looked at my Ubuntu machine and I found .zf.ini file is at home directory. Its content is fine too and ZF works finely on Ubuntu with Netbeans and the terminal. The problem is on the Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this [Getting codeception & phpunit working on MAMP with OS X Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8995633/1145086)
it seems that MAMP's php may compete with the OS X previously installed PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I'd experience the same problem too, long time ago.

You have to edit you .zf.ini file in your home directory /Users/myuser
and put the right path to the NetBeansCommandsProvider.php this file can be found on 
/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/php/zend

Here is my .zf.ini file

```
php.include_path = "/Users/myuser/Programs/ZendFrameworkCli/library:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/php/zend:.:/usr/lib/php"
```

basicloader.classes.0 = "NetBeansCommandsProvider"

Regards